# High predicted R2 in training data but low accuracy on test data set

Tags: neural-networks, multiple-regression, linear-model

I'm building a regression model to predict airline prices using python. I have three inputs mean , median and no of days from departure, and dataset greater than 100000 data points crawled at daily intervals. I used the log of the input variables and  divided the dataset into 80:20 for training and and testing purposes.Im getting a high predicted R2 (greater than 80 percent) on training data. However the accuracy (predicted data points within 5 percent deviation of the actual price) is neither good on 20 percent dataset ie.20000 data points which are within the same route as training, on different departure dates and neither on totally unforeseen routes. 
Why is there a  mismatch between R2 predicted and accuracy ? Do i need to compute the Root Mean Squared Error instead of calculating the number of predicted values within 5 % deviation of the observed values to know the prediction accuracy ?

I've constructed a X.Y scatter of predicted vs actual. I reduced the data set to 510 data points and used 489 data points for training, 21 data points from the same route and another 63 data points for testing on different route .This time the R2 predicted dropped to 60 percent on training set. Results are as follows

Graph 1 is where test data is from the same route. ie 510-489 = 21 data points. Accuracy is horrible both in terms of
a) No of predicted data points within 5 percent of observed (14.28 percent) as well as
b) Root mean squared error which is 2979 which is huge.
Predicted vs Actual - Bombay -  Calcutta - Test data points are same route as training.
[image: Calcutta Bombay]

Graph 2 is where the test data points are 63 in number for Ahmadabad - Calcutta which is a totally different route.

[image: Ahmedabad Calcutta]

This time accuracy is slightly improved.
a) No of predicted data points within 5 percent of observed (33 percent) as well as
b) Root mean squared error which is 2246 which is huge.
Predicted vs Actual - Bombay -  Calcutta - Test data points are same route as training

Comment: Can you show any diagnostic plots? What do residuals look like? Is the data skewed? Etc..

Comment: Hello Jon. Have made the update as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is classic overfitting. Your model has a high R2 because it's fitted to non-predictive noise in your training data and consequently doesn't generalize well, hence the low accuracy on your test set. Try training on more features if you can find data. Otherwise, consider trying different families of models and/or applying regularization.

Comment: Hello David. I had around 40 extremely relevant variables. But a lot of them remain as zero in the neural network since they are tied to a single departure date.So i removed them and kept the above ones where there is a variation. Now with respect to price , the current price is one of the predictors(input) and the future price is the output but most of the times they remain equal. Any thoughts?

Comment: There's all sorts of features you could use to augment this. Just think about buying a ticket yourself. Departure and destination cities, departure and arrival time of day/day of week, proximity to holidays, time of year... There are loads of different features you could use to augment this.

Comment: A lot of them are similar to mine as mentioned. But since they are tied to a single departure date ,for most flights they are treated as zero(no change) by the neural network. Any ideas on how to improvise the current model ?

Comment: I don't really have enough context here, tbh. And I'm fairly certain this discussion is getting well out of scope of your question, which was specifically about the how your high R2 and low holdout accuracy came about. Maybe you should post a separate question describing your problem more if you want to seek advice for how to improve your model.

Comment: Noted. Have added a follow up question.    https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/328826/184106

Answer (score 2):

@David Marx diagnosis is most likely correct. You have a data set with many variables, and the model is learning well the form of your traning set, however, it is not generalizing well. @David Marx recommends adding more features, I think this is already the problem. You want to reduce the number of features as they may be producing collinearity. Applying regularization on to your methodology would surely benefit you, albeit, may not solve everything. Consider various methods of feature selection.

Some methods for reducing overfitting include:

1. More data
2. Regularization
3. Simpler models with less parameters (feature selection)
4. Reducing dimensionality of the data